# How to ignore an Azure subscription from a particular tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio professional and trying to use Cloud Explorer for my Azure account. My email is part of two tenants, lets say A and B. "A" is my home org. Whenever I try to key in azure credentials for the Cloud explorer, it keeps asking me to do MFA for tenant B for which I don't have any means to do a MFA. I uninstalled the authenticator app and could not reinstall. I am able to login to tenant A without any issues in the browser. Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to not bother with tenant B's subscriptions?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to ignore a directory by following the steps.

1. Go to Help -> Register product
   2. Choose "Account Options"
   3. Uncheck "Authenticate across all Azure Active Directories" and click Ok